# Query a JSON column with an array of object in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a json column with the follow array:

```
[
  {
    "id": "24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31",
    "key": "id",
    "type": "input",
  },
  {
    "id": "e0ca5aa1-359f-4460-80ad-70445be49644",
    "key": "name",
    "type": "textarea",
    }
]
```

I tried the follow query to get the row that has the id `24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31` in the document column, but it returns not results:

```
select * from jobs WHERE document->'$[*].id' = "24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31"
```

Anyone know how to do the right query?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 44):

I use mysql 5.7 and so JSON_CONTAINS can be easily used like this:

```
SELECT JSON_CONTAINS(
                '[{"id": "24av","name": "she"},{"id": "e0c2", "name": "another_she"}]', 
                JSON_OBJECT('id', "e0c2")
                );
```

Comment: I don't understand what this is. Why is there an array of objects passed as the first parameter to JSON_CONTAINS when this array of objects is supposed to be a value in a column, and the query is supposed to find the object that has some matching parameter to the query. It doesn't make any sense to me at all.

Comment: @John That first parameter can be the the column from your table, here he is hardcoding the columns value so that you can run this query without any table.

Comment: Just to add to the answer given by @Sep, you can query on multiple attributes in the json object as follows:
`SELECT JSON_CONTAINS('[{"id": "24av","name": "she"},{"id": "e0c2", "name": "another_she"}]', JSON_OBJECT('id',"e0c2",'name',"another_she"));`

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I am kind of wondering what this would look like if you wernt hardcoding values - practically speaking, if I'm querying JSON from a DB I don't have these values yet right?

Answer (score 23):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE document->'$[*].id' = json_array("24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31");
```

It works for me, but I think the below way is more better:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE json_contains(document->'$[*].id', json_array("24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31"));
```

Actually It's easy just remember the return value is `JSON_TYPE` but not a String or something else;

Comment: The second solution is the perfect one!

Answer (score 5):

maybe this? @Barmar

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE JSON_SEARCH(document, "one", "24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31", NULL, '$[*].id') IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use `document->'$[*].id'` it returns a comma-delimited list of all the ID properties. This won't be equal to the value of just one ID string, unless there's only one object in the `document` column.

You need to use `JSON_SEARCH()` to search for a matching element within the JSON value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM jobs 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(document, "one", "24276e4b-de81-4c2c-84e7-eed9c3582a31", NULL, '$[*].id');
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, but using json_search still returns 0 rows

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a MySQL 5.7 instance to test on.