# mysql how to query nested json element?

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

so here is the schema for the JSON :

```json
{
  "ts": 1677330162,
  "uuid": "75e4917d-69cd-49e1-963f-380ea031a88b",
  "moderators": [
    {
      "userId": "000001",
      "timeAdded": 1677332262,
      "permissions": {
        "all": true,
        "tag": true,
        "mail": true,
        "posts": true,
        "access": true,
        "config": true,
        "analytics": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "lastUpdated": 1677332262
}
```

which is stored as
[image]

i have tried all of these queries:

[Query a JSON column with an array of object in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797627/query-a-json-column-with-an-array-of-object-in-mysql)

and nothing is working, mysql doesnt give an error, just no results.

my last query i tried:

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM community__sharded 
 WHERE data->'$.moderators.*.userId' = json_array(000001);
```

i have no idea where im going wrong, can i get some help?

update:
my end goal is to get the JSON key "userId:xx", but the moderators key is an array, so i cant just do moderators.userId:xx,

solved below (sorry for lack of info in the beginning, was half asleep)

Comment: So, what's the question and the expected result?

Comment: Try using `JSON search function`? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json_array(000001) will output [1] not [000001]

So it must be casted to varchar

```
SELECT * FROM community__sharded 
WHERE data->'$.moderators[*].userId' = json_array("000001");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON_SEARCH:

```
SELECT *
FROM community__sharded
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(data, 'one', '000001', NULL, '$.moderators[*].userId') IS NOT NULL;
```

Quoting the docs:

> JSON_SEARCH(json_doc, one_or_all, search_str[, escape_char[, path] ...])
>
> - Returns the path to the given string within a JSON document. Returns
>   NULL if any of the json_doc, search_str, or path arguments are NULL;:

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select * from community__sharded cs
join json_table(
    cs.data ->> '$.moderators',
    '$[*]'
    columns (
        `id` for ordinality ,
        `userId` varchar(10) path '$.userId'
        )
    ) as mo 
where mo.userId='00001'
```